# Could not convert string to float in input

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
  #My code should take a random between 1 and 100 and let you guess it. 
#This part works, but I want to add the posibility to reveal the number and then is when I get the error "could not convert string to float"
    def reveal(guess):
        return secret_number
    import random 

    secret_number = random.random()*100  
    guess = float(input("Take a guess: ")) #This is the input

    while secret_number != guess :

        if guess < secret_number:
            print("Higher...")
        elif guess > secret_number:
            print("Lower...")
        guess = float(input("Take a guess: ")) #This input is here in order for the program not to print Higher or Lower without ever stopping

    else:
        print("\nYou guessed it! The number was " ,secret_number)
    if guess == "reveal": #This is where I "tried" to make the reveal thingy.
        print ("Number was", secret_number)
    input("\n\n Press the enter key to exit")
```

## Any help would be a great service. Also I am only programming for just a few weeks so sorry if my code looks wrong.

Comment: Could you fix up the indentation please?

Comment: What are you actually inputting in your program?

Comment: String to float? You could totally find that on pydocs or google in seconds. This question is not particularly useful, and seriously lacks research.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to formulate questions which would be helpful for others for decades to come, and not just solve your immediate task with unreal/impractical constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

LOWEST = 1
HIGHEST = 100

def main():
    print('Guess the secret number between {} and {}!'.format(LOWEST, HIGHEST))
    secret = random.randint(LOWEST, HIGHEST)

    tries = 0
    while True:
        guess = raw_input('Your guess: ').strip().lower()
        if guess.isdigit():
            tries += 1
            guess = int(guess)
            if guess < secret:
                print('Higher!')
            elif guess > secret:
                print('Lower!')
            else:
                print('You got it in {} tries!'.format(tries))
                break
        elif guess == "reveal":
            print('The secret number was {}'.format(secret))
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter a number between {} and {}'.format(LOWEST, HIGHEST))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It doesn't work for numbers like 59.5. And when I add float to the input it just breaks.

Comment: Why on Earth would you ever play the guessing game with floating-point numbers? It takes the number of guesses required from "about 8" to "about 30"; it's the same as playing "guess the number between 1 and 4.3 billion".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use float number to compare, the game may be endless because a float number has  many fractional digits. Use int number.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3
# coding: utf-8

import random


def guess_number():
    try:
        guess = int(input("Take a guess:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, you should input a number")
        guess = -1
    return guess


if __name__ == '__main__':
    secret_number = int(random.random() * 100)
    while True:
        guess = guess_number()
        if guess == -1:
            continue
        elif guess < secret_number:
            print("Lower...")
        elif guess > secret_number:
            print("Higher...")
        else:
            print("\nYou got it! The number was ", secret_number)
            input("\n\nPress any key to exit.")
            break # or 'import sys; sys.exit(0)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could isolate concerns by defining a function that asks user for input until a float is provided:

```
def input_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("You should input a float number. Try again.")
```

Then you could use it in your script:

```
guess = input_float("Take a guess: ")
```

If you want to accept `'reveal'` as an input in addition to a float number:

```
def input_float_or_command(prompt, command='reveal'):
    while True:
        s = input(prompt)
        if s == command:
           return s
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            print("You should input a float number or %r. Try again." % command)
```

Comment: I want to add the reveal function. If I add this function it won't work anymore

Comment: @user3026270: I've added support for 'reveal'.

Comment: Now I get  if guess < secret_number:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()

Comment: @user3026270: put `if guess == "reveal": ...` *before* it.

Answer (score 0):

Use random.range instead of random.random.

```
secret_number = random.range(1,100,1)
```

And `...,str(secret_number)`

```
...
else:
    print("\nYou guessed it! The number was " ,str(secret_number))
if guess == "reveal": #This is where I "tried" to make the reveal thingy.
    print ("Number was", str(secret_number))
...
```

That way you will be concatenating a string with a string. Also, you can keep random.random and only make the second change.

EDIT:

Another thing to do is to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. Then use `try`.

```
guess = raw_input("Take a guess: ")
try:
    guess = float(guess)
except:
    pass
```

This will try to convert guess into a float, and it that fails, then it will remain a string. That should solve your problem.

Comment: This doesn't actually do anything. ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'reveal'

Comment: Then try using random.range

Comment: When I use secret_number = random.range(1,100,1)  I get 'module' object has no attribute 'range'

Comment: See edit above. I found another mistake. Sorry, it should be random.randomrange not random.range